# Laravel CSV import only saves last row in DB (with id being incremented correctly)

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Using Laravel 6 and Laravel Excel 3.1, I try to import transactions from CSV file. 
I followed [the quickstart](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/).

The result is that only the last row is added to the database. The ID that is created is based on the correct amount of records. When I enable the progress bar I do see all rows are processed (but same result).

E.g. I start with empty database, I import 10 records, after import I see one row containing the values of the last row, with ID 10.

I added console command:

```
    $this->line('before  - count: '. Transaction::count() .' - last ID: '. Transaction::max('id'));
    Excel::import(new TransactionsImport, $file);
    $this->line('after  - count: '. Transaction::count() .' - last ID: '. Transaction::max('id'));
```

Example output when importing 3 records:

```
before - count: 27 - last ID: 77
after  - count: 28 - last ID: 80
```

When I import into a collection I see three items:

```
    $collection = Excel::toCollection(new TransactionsImport, $file);
    $this->line("raw CSV items imported into collection: ". $collection[0]->count() ); // 3
```

It returns collection in collection:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#975
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#978 // collection for 3 rows
      #items: array:3 [
        0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#981 // collection for 1 record
          #items: array:9 [
            "datum" => 20190905.0 // the original CSV labels+values
            ...
```

I created import model using `php artisan make:import TransactionsImport --model=Transaction`:

```
class TransactionsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Transaction([
            'date' => Carbon::parse($row['datum']),
            'name' => $row['naam_omschrijving'],
            'account' => $row['rekening'],
            'accountFrom' => $row['tegenrekening'],
            'mutationCode' => $row['code'],
            'afBij' => $row['af_bij'],
            'amount' => $row['bedrag_eur'],
            'mutationType' => $row['mutatiesoort'],
            'message' => $row['mededelingen'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Update**: added details about import into collection

**Update**: the behavior changes (but still erratic) when using `WithBatchInserts`. With `batchSize()` set to 5000: a file with 3829 records gets imported correctly, a file with 12657 records imports only the last 2657 records (the first 10000 are processed but not stored). When `batchSize()` is set to 13000 I run out of memory. Tried using `WithBatchInserts` and `chunkSize()` set to 5000, the import process then freezes 30+ seconds after 10000 records and eventually imports a total of 5171 records.

Comment: Have you tried to use $ModelObject->save() or $ModelObject->creat() functions of eloquent?

Comment: The documentation specifically says you should not save the model yourself. (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html): "The returned model will be saved for you. Each row will result into (at least) one save and will also fire model events.
When using ToModel you should never save the model yourself, as that will break the batch insert functionality. "